# I want to repent but unable to return stolen property. What can I do?

Tags: sharia

I took a notebook from the lab without any permission which comes under the stealing category. I passed out from school. There is no doubt I did wrong and I know that to be forgiven by Allah, We must return the goods to the lawful owner but the problem is that there is no connection of mine that exists there, no friends studying there.

I couldn't find any source through which I can return even if I mail them they might file a lawsuit against me. I want to repent to Allah and the problem is how.

I want to know what condition of shari'ah applied on me even if my condition is the worst.  Please help me!

Comment: In other words you want to ask Allah for forgiveness without giving back what you've seemingly stolen (or taken by mistake). While you know that for repentance asking forgiveness from the person you've wronged is the first step? You should give back the property and accept the consequences.